# Could not find a declaration file for module 'aws-jwt-verify'

Tags: aws-jwt-verify

After installing `aws-jwt-verify` (`npm install aws-jwt-verify`) the following error message is shown in my console

```
error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'aws-jwt-verify'. 'C:/projects/messenger-api/node_modules/aws-jwt-verify/dist/esm/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
  Try `npm i --save-dev @types/aws-jwt-verify` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'aws-jwt-verify';`

3 import { CognitoJwtVerifier } from 'aws-jwt-verify'
                                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    at createTSError (C:\projects\messenger-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:859:12)  
    at reportTSError (C:\projects\messenger-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:863:19)  
    at getOutput (C:\projects\messenger-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1077:36)     
    at Object.compile (C:\projects\messenger-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:1433:41)
    at transformSource (C:\projects\messenger-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:400:37)  
    at C:\projects\messenger-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:278:53
    at async addShortCircuitFlag (C:\projects\messenger-api\node_modules\ts-node\src\esm.ts:409:15)
    at async nextLoad (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:163:22)
    at async ESMLoader.load (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:601:20)
    at async ESMLoader.moduleProvider (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:457:11) {
  diagnosticCodes: [ 7016 ]
}
```

The `npm i --save-dev @types/aws-jwt-verify` command doesn't help to resolve the issue.

This is my `tsconfig.json` file

```json
{
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2022",
    "lib": [
      "ES2022"
    ],
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "outDir": "./build",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

I run my project with

```json
{
   "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts",
}
```

Comment: Was this solved? We added support for module resolution NodeNext in V3.3.0, may just help?

Comment: Thanks, @Otto! The error has been resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has been resolved after updating to version `aws-jwt-verify@4.0.0`.